# Centralizar texto em elemento, proporcionalmente

Tags: css

No exemplo abaixo usa-se,  `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`
para manter um texto no meio do elemento. Mas não é uma solução que funciona em todos os navegadores. Gostaria de fazer mesmo, mas com css simples ou até mesmo com jquery.

```css
.artigo-content {
    background: #fff;
    color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    padding: 0 30px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height:300px;
}

.artigo-inner {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="artigo-main">
  <div class="artigo-content">
    <div class="artigo-inner">
      <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at eleifend leo. Praesent eu ex ligula.</a></h3>
      <p>Abril 26, 2018</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O mais simples é mesmo `display:flex`

Comment: @Isac realmente a forma mais simples é com Flex indiscutível. Mas o suporte dos browsers ao Flex é ainda pior que ao Transform https://caniuse.com/

Comment: @hugocsl Embora o suporte ainda não seja a 100%. Todos eles suportam a partir de determinadas versões. O único patinho feio é o mesmo do costume, o IE, mas ai já seria de esperar. Com vendor prefixes ainda vai mais atrás nas versões.

Comment: @Isac Pois é o maldito IE sempre ele, mas muitas empresas só homologam para ele, pois isso pensando no que o autor da pergunta falou fiz o comentário.

Comment: Se está a utilizar o [`Bootstrap 4`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/), então você já está dando suporte apenas ao `IE 10`, e o IE desde a versão 9 dá suporte a [`transformações 2d`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A versão para esse tipo de alinhamento mais antiga que conheço seria com `display:table`, com isso vc não precisa usar tamanhos fixos. *(usando valores fixos também da para alinhar no centro)*

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.artigo-main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}
.artigo-content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fff;
    color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
}
.artigo-inner {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="artigo-main">
    <div class="artigo-content ">
        <div class="artigo-inner">
            <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at eleifend leo. Praesent eu ex ligula.</a></h3>
            <p>Abril 26, 2018</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solução perfeita.

Comment: É possivel usar isso dentro de uma grid do bootstrap? Estou tentando aqui, mas não funciona.

Comment: John tente colocar !important em todos os estilos que vc usar para fazer esse customização principalmente no que for display, vc vai ter que substituir as classes default do bootstrap por isso precisa do !important.

Comment: funciona bem sem precisar fazer nada, eu reproduzir o demo no codepen: https://codepen.io/johnquimera/full/PRjpOY/

Comment: @JohnQuimera ótimo, quanto menos interferir nos estilos nativos do Bootstrap melhor! Boa sorte com o projeto []'s Vi que vc está usando o Bootstrap 4 né, depois pesquise sobre a classe "d-flex" pode te ajudar com esses alinhamentos, é com flex, mas é nativo do BS4

Comment: usarei certamente em algum momento, mas sua solução resolve o problema com outros navegadores. Agora eu queria ver se seria possível colocar uma imagem de fundo nesse texto, mas sem ser com 'background-image', mas com `<img>` de modo que seja responsivo,. e o texto centralizado sempre se adapte ao tamanho da imagem.

Comment: @JohnQuimera cria uma pergunta nova para não bagunçar essa que já foi respondida e eu te ajudo lá. Provavelmente isso é possível de fazer sim! Vc quer que a imagem ocupe 100% da altura e largura de onde está dentro? Cria uma pergunta nova ai que eu te dou uma foça se estiver ao meu alcance.

Comment: acabei de criar. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286090/95735